# jQuery .text() issue

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery code:

```
$('.team-leader-id').delegate('button', 'click', function() {
    var parent_object = $(this);
    var admin_id = $(this).parents('.team_data').find('.leader-id').val();
    var team_id = $(this).parents('.team_data').find('.team-hidden-id').val();
    $(this).parents('.team_data').find('.team-leader-mod-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $(this).parents('.team_data').find('.team-leader-modify').html('Mégse');
    $(this).parents('.team_data').find('.ajax-json-response').fadeOut(1).html('');
    $(this).parents('.team_data').find('.ajax-json-loading').html('<img src="images/progress-dots.gif" />').fadeIn('slow');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'json.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        timeout: 20000,
        data: { a: 'change_team_admin', admin_id: admin_id, team_id: team_id },
        success: function(data) {
            $(parent_object).parents('.team_data').find('.ajax-json-loading').fadeOut(1).html('');
            $(parent_object).parents('.team_data').find('.ajax-json-response').html(data.message).fadeIn(400).delay(2000).slideUp(400);
            if (!data.error) {
                $(parent_object).parents('.team_data').find('.team-leader-id').html('<a href="http://lanseries.hu/index.php?oldal=profile&p_id='+admin_id+'" target="_blank">'+admin_id+'</a>');
                PROBLEM -->$(parent_object).parents('.team_data').find('.team-leader-modify').text('OKÉ');<--
            } else {
                $(parent_object).parents('.team_data').find('.team-leader-mod-button').removeAttr('disabled');
                $(parent_object).parents('.team_data').find('.team-leader-modify').html('<a href="javascript:void(0)">Mégse</a>');
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $(parent_object).parents('.team_data').find('.ajax-json-loading').fadeOut(1).html('');
            //$(parent_object).parents('.team_data').find('#ajax-json-response').html('Probléma történt! Kérlek próbáld újra később! (HTTP Error: '+errorThrown+' | Error Message: '+textStatus+')').fadeIn('slow');
            $(parent_object).parents('.team_data').find('#ajax-json-response').html('Probléma történt! Kérlek próbáld újra később, és ellenőrizd az internetkapcsolatod!').fadeIn('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

Everything is working well, it's ok, but one row not run! You can find it in the code.

```
PROBLEM -->$(parent_object).parents('.team_data').find('.team-leader-modify').text('OKÉ');<--
```

HTML: (There are some thousands of this code part, so I can't use `id`s everywhere.

```
<div class="dnone team_data" id="team_<?php echo $allnum; ?>" style="padding: 10px; margin: 2px 0 2px 0; border: 1px solid <?php echo $site_color; ?>;">
<div class="ajax-json-loading"></div>
<div class="ajax-json-response"></div>
<table cellspacing="5">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="width: 100px;">
            <b>Csapat vezető:</b>
        </td>
        <td class="team-leader-area">
            <input type="hidden" class="team-leader-hidden-id" value="<?php echo $value['leader']; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" class="team-hidden-id" value="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" />
            <div class="team-leader-id"><a href="http://lanseries.hu/index.php?oldal=profile&p_id=<?php echo $value['leader']; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $value['leader']; ?></a></div>
            <div class="team-leader-modify"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Módosít</a></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="width: 100px;">
            <b>Befizető címe:</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $value['p_address']; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Could you tell me why?

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Debug it. Do the jQuery statements actually manage to find an element that matches? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Couldn't you find a more descriptive title for your question?

Comment: Yes, it's the same, just the .text() changed. It must find!

Comment: Without seeing the HTML involved it's going to be kind-of hard for us to figure out the problem, don't you think?

Comment: Darin why do you waste you time here, if you don't like the title? l33t

Comment: Pointy: I don't think, because I've written that the other commands are working well, so the problem is in the JS not in the HTML.

Comment: Pekka: I don't get any errors.

Comment: @Skylineman, I am not wasting my time. I am just asking a question with the sole purpose of improving the quality of the questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I'm sorry, but I were not able to find a better one. I can't describe my problem...

Comment: So is the problem with .text() or with your selector? We can't help you without seeing your HTML. Try .remove() instead of .text() and see if the element is gone. And use an appropriate title, your current one is totally misleading.

Comment: @Skylineman, maybe you could provide a little context to your question. Like for example what you are trying to do. Show the relevant DOM structure that you are trying to manipulate. A [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example illustrating your problem would be great as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break it down.  I would put the following above the problem line and check the console in Chrome the entries exist:

```
console.dir($(parent_object).parents('.team_data'));
console.dir($(parent_object).parents('.team_data').find('.team-leader-modify'));
$(parent_object).parents('.team_data').find('.team-leader-modify').text('OKÉ');
console.dir($(parent_object).parents('.team_data').find('.team-leader-modify').text());
```

Also, I wouldn't make so many calls to `$(parent_object).parents('.team_data')`.  It's a somewhat costly operation.

Instead, at the beginning of the response functions do something like:

```
var $teamData = $(parent_object).parents('.team_data');
```

Then reference $teamData for your remaining jQuery calls.

Comment: consolse shows: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[0]
javascripts.js:206
jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[0]

Comment: You should be able to click on the left arrow next to each item and expand.  Ideally when you click the first it will show you one element with class "team_data".  The second one should show you a single element with "team-leader-modify"

Comment: Thank you, it's working now with your `$teamData` idea. I had too much of that `$(parent_object).parents('.team_data')`. Thanks!